# Discord.JS Minecraft Server Embed

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to have my bot send an embed with the details of the Hypixel Minecraft Server, and I have:
`const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() .setTitle('Server Status') .addField('Server IP', response.host) .addField('Server Version', response.version)  .addField('Online Players', response.onlinePlayers) .addField('Max Players', response.maxPlayers)`

but I don't know where to input this into my code, which is:

client.on('message', message =>{
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ')

```
switch(args[0]){
    case 'mc':
        


        ping('play.hypixel.net', { port: 25565 })

.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch((error) => {
    throw error;
    
});

}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it right after the `console.log` or instead of it

```js
.then((response) => {
const myepicEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(...)
...
message.channel.send(myepicEmbed)
})
```

Remember that for adding multiple fields you can use `.addFields()` it would look like this

```js
const myepicEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
.addFields(
{
 name: "I am the first field!",
 value: "Yes I am"
},
{

//But name and value isn't needed so you can just write
 "I am the second field!",
 "Sadly not the first"
},
{
...
});
message.channel.send(myepicEmbed);
```

If you want more information about using embeds, check [Embed Related Chapter on Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)!